# Y-Axis values scaling on Dygraph with specific intervals

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I have been trying to create the Dygraph (for JavaScript) with specific intervals on the y-axis, but wasn't able to do so.

I have tried `pixelsPerLabel`, but it doesn't give up the pixel value of `0.25`. Is there any option to set intervals for the y-axis?

Here's my working example:

[image: Click this link for image]

I want to have y-axis values with an interval of 0.25

Comment: It would help quite a bit if you provide the code which you are currently using, as it can *greatly* reduce the effort necessary to answer your question and make answers more directly relevant to you. See [mre]. Contact outside of Stack Overflow is discouraged. The primary purpose of Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange in general) is to develop a repository of questions and answers which are valuable to future visitors. Moving discussion off-site or having necessary code/data off-site is counter to that purpose, as it makes any affected questions or answers not very useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom function to generate the axis ticks, called the `ticker`. This is defined in the axis options when you create the DyGraph:

```js
var g = new DyGraph(
  document.getElementById("graph"),
  graphData,
  {
    axes: {
      y: {
        ticker: function(min, max, pixels) {
          ticks = [];
          for (var i = min; i <= max; i = i + 0.25) {
            ticks.push({v: i});
            ticks.push({label_v: i, label: i});
          }
          return ticks;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This is a very simple example that just uses a simple `for` loop - obviously you can adjust it to do whatever fancy things you desire, but this will give you ticks every 0.25 units.